# Можно ли упростить данный sql запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос к базе данных MySql

```
select FirstName, LastName, runner.Email, RegistrationStatus
from registrationevent
     inner join registration on registration.RegistrationId = registrationevent.RegistrationId 
     inner join registrationstatus on registration.RegistrationStatusId = registrationstatus.RegistrationStatusId 
     inner join runner on runner.RunnerId = registration.RunnerId 
     inner join user on user.Email = runner.Email
     inner join event on event.EventId = registrationevent.EventId 
     inner join eventtype on event.EventTypeId = eventtype.EventTypeId 
where RegistrationDateTime like '%2017%' and EventTypeName='Full Marathon'
```

[image: Все делается в такой базе данных]

Можно ли его упростить? И если можно, то как?

Comment: Смотря что вы подразумеваете под словом "Упростить".

Comment: Добавь , что сделал сам и что получается

Comment: Вроде как нет. Все таблицы нужны...

Comment: Я бы объединил таблицы `Runner` и `User`, они разбиты нелогично. А в запросе упрощать нечего.

Comment: Ну это олимпиадное задание, так что я не знаю можно их соединять или нет. Но спасибо за ответы :)

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan я подразумевал сделать его как-то меньше

Comment: @ДанилАндреевский как минимум не ясно, что ожидается увидеть на выходе

Comment: Какой тип данных у RegistrationDateTime?
Использовать строку и, соответственно, like - не лучший вариант.

Comment: @Danilolegovich2 Что бы запрос стал меньше в размере можно заменить `inner join` на запятые и перенести все условия соединения в where, заодно добавив таблицам однобуквенные алиасы, что бы в условиях не писать названия таблиц полностью. хотя это и чисто косметическое "упрощение"

Comment: или, учитывая что названия колонок одинаковые, заменить `inner join` на `natural join`, но это надо делать очень аккуратно, убедившись, что названия не ключевых колонок у таблиц не пересекаются

Comment: @Mike что-то я не могу найти документации по natural join. Что это такое?

Comment: @Danilolegovich2 google: "MySQL natural join". Это обычный join но в нем не надо указывать условие ON с указанием клонок по которым идет объединение. Он использует все одноименные колонки в таблицах для связи

Comment: @Mike Спасибо большое